# How to pass credentials when accessing SSRS report through URLs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to access a SSRS report using URL like in Expression `="javascript:void(window.open('http://servername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fTransaction_All_Reports%2fCustomer_+Payment_Receipt_Report&rs:Command=Render+Name &ReportParameter1=" & Fields!CustTransID.Value & " &rs:Command=Render','_blank' ,'resizeable=1,toolbar=0,status=0,menu=0,top=20,left=20,width=1040,height=1040'))"`

When I try to access above Url, I am asked for my network credentials, giving which I get all pages of SSRS report rendered in browser window.

Now I want to display these contents in a popup window inside my webApp. When i try to open it asks credentials,

What i need is it possible to give credentials inside above code block? like my username and password,

I need its directly open w/o asks credenetials

Can anyone help me please ,it save my life...

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the user's browser settings, you may be able to send credentials in the URL. This is generally disabled, though, because it leaves the user password in plaintext.

If accessing the server with Internet Explorer you can use Windows integrated authentication to pass the current user credentials automatically. This depends on the IE security settings.

Otherwise I don't think there's is a good way. Anonymous access to the SSRS server is not recommended, and hard to configure.

If it were my solution, I would have the server side code connect to the SSRS server, retrieve the report and then resend that stream to the user.

Comment: These are different credentials. It wants credentials for the data source. You have to explictly pass a username and password. You can do this via the web service with the SetExecutionCredentials method. He is asking how to do this in the URL query string.

Comment: @JonGrant Can you suggest somethin?